# Commenting out code in eclipse adding **** automatically between /* and */

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

While commenting lines of code in eclipse kepler using /* */. After save * added automatically at starting of each line. How to prevent automatic addition of the * char.

Example:
**Before comment**

```
public static int factorial(int n)
    {   int result = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }
```

**After Comment**

```
    /*public static int factorial(int n)
    {   int result = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }*/
```

**After Saving Java Code in Eclipse kepler**

```
    /*
     * public static int factorial(int n) { int result = 1; for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) result *= i; return result; }
     */
```

**And when uncomment this code**

```
* public static int factorial(int n) { int result = 1; for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) result *= i; return result; }
```

it is like that so it takes more time to remove * chars.

Kindly help me how to remove this atuto feature.

Comment: Not an answer to how to stop it doing that, but if you comment out using ctrl-/ (cmd-/ on mac) it'll use single line // comments rather than block comments which (a) don't get reflowed by the formatter and (b) can be uncommented with the same key shortcut.

Comment: Yes lan I already using ctrl-/ for time being but I want permanent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project/workspace preferences, formatter (java code style), edit the profile (you have to copy an existing one if you don’t have one yet, you cannot edit the Eclipse [built-in]), Comments and uncheck „Enable block comment formatting“. This disables all formatting for block comments when you save/format your code.

If you don't want this for all block comments, go to the Off/On Tags also in the formatter and enable the tags. You can now //@formatter:off or //@formatter:on enable them for specific sections and disable all formattings for the defined section.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this menu:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Save Action (Action performed on save)

If the "Format Source Code" checkbox is checked also look at this

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Here you can edit the action that the formatter performs for all the things of code

For disable block comment uncheck the "Enable block comment formatting"